# Android - Canvas drawBitmap inside specific area

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to draw a bitmap in my canvas inside a specific borders,
i'm trying to dynamically change the x,y position of this bitmap - and i want it no to show outside of a specific borders

(image explanation):
[image]

i know i can draw the box image ontop of the pacman image - but i'm looking for another solution (if possible)

Comment: you can try with Canvas.clipRect or any other clip**** methods?

Comment: why do you want to use separated images? In this case i think only 1 is needed.